Typescript class doesn't allow static async method overloading
I'm trying to overload the login function so that when i pass in an argument to it the return type gets inferred as LoginResponse and when i don't pass any arguments it gets inferred as void | Error. I am using the singleton pattern so that's why i have the fields at the top defined like that
Here is the relevant part of my class
export default class AuthAPI {
  private static instance: AuthAPI;
  private serverToken: string;
  private constructor(serverToken: string) {
    this.serverToken = serverToken;
  }
  static async login(loginData: LoginData): Promise<LoginResponse>;
  static async login(): Promise<Error | void>;
  // login method if there is loginData given
  static async login(
    loginData?: LoginData,
  ): Promise<LoginResponse | Error | void> {
    /** try sending a request with localStorage token
     * and if there's a 401 error the token isn't valid anymore.
     * then try logging in with loginData */

    // try signing in with local token in storage
    if (loginData === undefined) {
      // try sending a request and if there's a 401 error the token isn't valid anymore

      if (Math.random() * 1000 === 401) {
        return new Error("Token expired; Couldn't log in locally");
      }
      if (Math.random() * 1000 === 200) {
        return;
      }
    }
    if (loginData) {
      // if not log in with a request to the server
      return {token: 'a string', user: 'user'};
    }
  }
}

the relevant types are:
export interface LoginData {
  loginEmail?: string;
  username?: string;
  password: string;
}
export type LoginResponse = {
  token: string;
  user: string;
};

This is my eslint config
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: '@react-native-community',
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.ts', '*.tsx'],
      rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/no-shadow': ['error'],
        'no-shadow': 'off',
        'no-undef': 'off',
        'react-native/no-inline-styles': 0,
        'prettier/prettier': [
          'error',
          {
            'no-inline-styles': false,
          },
        ],
        'react/self-closing-comp': 'off',
        'no-unused-vars': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'off',
        'react-hooks/rules-of-hooks': 'off',
        'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'off',
      },
    },
  ],
};

I get a Duplicate name 'login' eslint no-dupe-class-members error in vscode. How do i fix it?

I Checked if there were multiple implementations and there aren't. I tried reproducing the problem on replit playground and there was no error. i think the problem is eslint.

Please [edit] to provide a [mre] where we can see what you're seeing if we copy and paste it into our own IDEs. My IDE doesn't know what LoginData or LoginResponse or response or response2 is. Additionally, no-dupe-class-members is apparently not needed when using TypeScript. Can you turn off that rule?

When i reproduced on replit there weren't any errors. i believe this is a vscode only error. or at least eslint's.

If you can't provide a [mre] this question risks being closed as lacking debugging details. Please start trying to isolate the cause of the issue and document enough of your config in an [edit] that others could reproduce.  You've got "typescript-eslint" as a tag but I think both eslint and typescript-eslint have a no-dupe-class-members rule, so it would be helpful for you to provide details.

yes they do have that rule and it was enforced. that's why i'm getting the error.

I solved it!
The problem was that my default eslint configuration had "no-duplicate-class-members" on. I turned it off because it isn't needed, as @jcalz said, and now it's fixed.

Accept the answer will help other search more effectively :)
